# ¿Como obtener el Id del ultimo registro Insertado en MongoDB y C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb

Estoy trabajando con MongoDB y c#, esta es la manera en que Inserto Datos.

### *Mi Clase Empleados*

```
    public class Empleados
    {
        public string Nombre{ get; set; }
        public string Direccion { get; set; }
    }
```

### Método del Botón

```
Empleados empleado= new Empleados ();
empleado.Nombre= "Rastalovely";
empleado.Direccion= "Mexico";
Insert_Empleados(empleado);
```

### Método Privado

```
private void Insert_Empleados(Empleados empleado)
    {
        var coleccion = data.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("empleados");
        BsonDocument documento = empleado.ToBsonDocument();
        coleccion.InsertOne(documento);
    }
```

> Lo que Necesito es obtener el Id del ultimo empleado agregado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar

```
SortByBuilder sbb = new SortByBuilder();
sbb.Descending("_id");
var ultimo = coleccion.FindAllAs<BsonDocument>().SetSortOrder(sbb).SetLimit(1);
```

extraido de la [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11933760/how-to-get-last-n-documents-from-collection-in-mongo) de stack over flow en ingles

**EDIT**

```
var sortBy = SortBy.Descending("_id");
var ultimo = coleccion.FindAs<BsonDocument>().SetSortOrder(sortby).SetLimit(1);
```

Prueba :

```
private void Insert_Empleados(Empleados empleado)
{
    var coleccion = data.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("empleados");
    BsonDocument documento = empleado.ToBsonDocument();
    coleccion.InsertOne(documento);
    SortByBuilder sbb = new SortByBuilder();
    sbb.Descending("_id");
    var ultimo = coleccion.FindAllAs<BsonDocument>().SetSortOrder(sbb).SetLimit(1);
}
```

**EDIT 2**

```
coleccion.Find().SetSortOrder(SortBy.Descending("_id")).SetLimit(1);
```

Comment: en que parte va el codigo, ademas de que ,marca error en FindAllAs

Comment: Que error te marca @Rastalovely

Comment: No existe FindAllAs...

Comment: Prueba con FindAs, edite mi respuesta

Comment: @Rastalovely me parece que la primera opción que te sugiere sioesi debe funcionar sin problema, pero el ordenamiento definido debe ser sbb.Descending("_id");

Comment: @Elenasys toda la razon! Se me fue! Edito

Comment: @sioesi stoy revisando... mientras gracias!

Comment: Me marca error en coleccion.FindAllAs y FindAs

Comment: Estas poniendo mi respuesta dentro del metodo InsertEmpleado?

Comment: @Rastalovely que error es el que marca?

Comment: <BsonDocument> no contiene una definicion para FindAllAs ni para Find As, el codigo lo escribe como me puso @sioesi la parte de Prueba

Comment: @Rastalovely prueba con el segundo edit que hice

Comment: @Rastalovely Que versión de Driver usas en C# para mongodb? sioesi, me parece que es su driver, los 2 métodos son validos.

Comment: Eso es lo que me causa duda, su version de driver porque deberia funcionar sin problemas ambos metodos... :s @Elenasys

Comment: Muchas Gracias @sioesi y Elenasys he resuelto mi problema he anotado la respuesta. Saludos

Comment: Yo esta solución la veo no muy buena, porque quién te dice que en el momento de obtener el último `_id`, ya habido uno o muchos documentos insertados.

Comment: Cual seria la mejor solucion segun tu? Si no hay manera de obtener un _id si aun no esta insertada? Como adivino yo cuando hacen un insert justo despues de yo obtener la ultima? Esta respuesta responde totalmente a lo que el OP pide, obtener el ultimo id insertado en el momento que yo lo consulto, si un milisegundo despues se inserto otra, toca volver a consultar

Answer (score 0):

Como pude Resolver mi Problema, gracias a  [@sioesi](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/16349/sioesi)  y [@Elenasys](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/95/elenasys)

### *Mi Clase Empleados*

```
    public class Empleados
    {
        public string Nombre{ get; set; }
        public string Direccion { get; set; }
    }
```

### Método del Botón

```
Empleados empleado= new Empleados ();
empleado.Nombre= "Rastalovely";
empleado.Direccion= "Mexico";
Insert_Empleados(empleado);
```

### Método Privado

```
private void Insert_Empleados(Empleados empleado)
    {
        var coleccion = data.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("empleados");
        BsonDocument documento = empleado.ToBsonDocument();
        coleccion.InsertOne(documento);

        var query = Query.Empty;
        var sortby = SortBy.Descending("_id");
        var afs0= coleccion.FindAs<BsonDocument>(query).SetSortOrder(sortby).SetLimit(1);

        var listado = afs0.ToList();
        foreach (var item in listado)
        {
            string elid = item["_id"].ToString();
        }
   }
```